# How can i change the Z-Index of mat-dialog in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

My app uses multiple mat-dialogs and sometimes it can happen that 2 are displayed at same time which causes a problem as the second one is never displayed correct and since its modal renders the app useless. After some more research it seems i can adjust the z-index for the mat-dialog via

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
z-index: 500 !important;
```

}

But that wont solve my problem as it will change the z-index for all to 500. My question is how can i change the Z-index only for certain mat-dialogs. For example all my basic dialogs can be one z-index as they will never show at same time and then i have dialogs which will alert or warn users which have to go above these basic ones. What is the best way to make it somewhat user configurable ?

Comment: Maybe using a dialog is not the right solution for your case. Consider something else? Sounds like you're trying to make a sausage be a chicken, which it is not. The dialog that is instatiated last, is supposed to be on top and that's how dialogs work.

Comment: Dialogs are bad to use and I try not to use them at all. With no dialogs, the website is much easier to test and more mobile-friendly. So my website would rarely have 1 dialog visible and never 2 dialogs visible, you should consider a different path.

Comment: Where does it say that you can not have multiple mat-dialog's on a page ? If that's the case please show me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When opening dialog you can provide [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) into `open` method. One property of config is `panelClass`. So in your global styles you can have a class that will change the `z-index`, only if the class is applied to the modal via config.

styles.css

```
.warning-dialog {
    z-index: 500 !important;
}
```

and then when opening the dialog you can pass class name in the config:

```
this.dialog.open(
    YourComponent,
    {
        panelClass: 'warning-dialog'
    }
);
```

Also consider removing `!important` from your styles, it usually creates problems in the future with maintainability of styles.

Comment: This solution is not working. I have the same issue, I work with @angular/cdk/dialog, but it is the same as Mat Dialog. Changing `panelClass` will add additional class to the the `cdk-overlay-pane`.  `z-index` must be changed on the parent `cdk-overlay-container` element for this to work.